# /etc/bashrc overrides my settings in home .bashrc

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc, etc

i have the following code for my prompt in .bashrc in home dir:

```
PS1_TIME='\033[01;31m\]\t \033[01;32m\]'
PS1_USERNAME='\[\e[1;36m\]\u\e[1;37m\]@\e[1;32m\]\h\[\033[00m\]'
PS1_LOCATION='\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]'

PS1=$PS1_TIME$PS1_USERNAME':'$PS1_LOCATION'\n\$ '
PS2='\[\033[01;36m\]>'
```

I have also the following configuration in /etc/bashrc

```
# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*|vte*)
      if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
      elif [ "${VTE_VERSION:-0}" -ge 3405 ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"
      else
          PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "1\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
      fi
      ;;
    screen*)
      if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
          PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
      else
          PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "2\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
      ;;
    esac
  fi
```

The result is that my shell prompt is configured of two:
prompt from /etc is merged with my home settings

```
[PS1 from ect][PS1 from home dir]:
```

How to change my local settings so my home dir will override the default ones?

I don't want to change the file in etc or do i have to?

Comment: `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: there are some differences between gnu_terminal and terminal behavior in OSs. generally `.bashrc` overwrite `/etc/bashrc`. anyway, I guessed `source ~/.bashrc` sould solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` are two different variables with different purposes. And, [as Bash manual states](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables):

> `PROMPT_COMMAND`
>
> > If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt (`$PS1`).

Note that `PROMPT_COMMAND` is not intended to be used as the prompt, but as a command to be executed before the actual prompt is printed.

To fix this, and if you don't want to edit your `/etc/bashrc`, you need to either unset or assign a null value to `PROMPT_COMMAND` in your local `.bashrc`:

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
# or
PROMPT_COMMAND=
```

---

Example in an interactive session (`foobar$` is my initial prompt):

```
foobar$ printf 'PROMPT_COMMAND: [%s]\nPS1: [%s]\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND" "$PS1"
PROMPT_COMMAND: [printf foo]
PS1: [bar$ ]
foobar$
```

Unsetting `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
foobar$ unset PROMPT_COMMAND
bar$
```

Assigning a null value to `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
foobar$ PROMPT_COMMAND=
bar$
```